# Is there any alternative for isDisplay() method in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, methods, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am trying to use isDisplay() method in my selenium script.

While I am using this method I have found this method returns false every time.

Is there any other way to use this method or alternative of this method?

Scroll_UP is done successfully. But If element is display, Scroll_UP is not terminate.And I need return value also.

Thanks in advance.

---

code logic which I write

```
public static boolean scroll_Up_Until_FindWebe(WebElement dragEle, WebElement ele, int scrollPoint)
{
int numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarUp = -10;
for (int i = scrollPoint; i > 10; i = i +numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarUp)
{
if (ele.isDisplayed()) //if the tag options is displayed
{
Log4J.logp.info("Ending scroll_Up_Until_FindWebe - Element is found");
return true;
}
dragger.moveToElement(dragEle).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0,numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarUp).release().build().perform();
}
Thread.sleep(500);
return scroll_Up_Until_FindWebe(dragEle, ele, 30);
}
```

Comment: Please share exact scenario and your web driver code.

Comment: Please check this method.

Comment: Perhaps also explain why it shouldn't be false. What code is used to keep it visible to the user?

Comment: Yes. ele.isDisplayed() this line.